# Python groupby(). What does [1:4] mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python.  Can anybody break down the process here per line?
What does the `[1:4]` do? Thank you.

```
def answer_six(): 
    copy_df = census_df.copy()
    copy_df = copy_df.groupby(['STNAME']) 
    states_pop = pd.DataFrame(columns=['pop'])
    for i, c in copy_df: 
        states_pop.loc[i] = [c.sort_values(by='CENSUS2010POP', ascending=False)[1:4]['CENSUS2010POP'].sum()]
        top3 = states_pop.nlargest(3,'pop') 
    return states_pop answer_six()
```

Comment: [edit] the code in the question here, not in comment. Remove the picture

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Answer (score 1):

`[1:4]` slices the `list` or a `tuple` object. It means that it will generate new `list` from the original one by getting items of the `list` oject from index `1` to index `4`.

*Note that the first item of the original list and items after index 4 (fifth item will be included in the new generated list) are removed.*